Expectation value of an observable and transition amplitude
Let's consider an arbitrary observable A and a quantum system:
$\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$ would be the expectation value of this observable for when the system finds itself in the state $|\psi\rangle$, which is not necessarily an eigenstate of some other observable. I am trying to generalize.
But if we have $\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle$, so two different states, this is now a transition amplitude.
Now, how can I argue that from this : $\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle$ which what we get is a transition amplitude, if we switch $|\phi\rangle\rightarrow |\psi\rangle$, then suddenly $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$ is interpetated as expectation value ?
But I believe it's also worth asking:
How can one show that $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$ does indeed represent the expectation value of the observable A. In Cohen Tannoudji - "Intro to QM" he just says that that's what it represents but he doesn't show how he comes to this conclusion.

Regarding the last part: It comes from the Born rule. That being said, it is not clear what the first part of your question is supposed to mean.

Well essentially I am asking, how do we come up with the idea that $\langle \psi|A|\phi\rangle$ can be interpreted as transition probability. And under what grounds/arguments you can say that the transition amplitude become expectation value when i.e $\phi \rightarrow \psi$. Quantum Mechanics did explain the born rule part. So I am clear on that

@imbAF $\langle \psi |A|\phi \rangle$ cannot be interpreted as a "transition probability", but it is simply a matrix element of the operator $A$. The fact that $\langle \psi | A |\psi\rangle$ is the expectation value of the observable $A=A^\dagger$ in the pure state represented by the state vector $| \psi \rangle$ (i.e. $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle=1$) is an axiom, there is nothing to "show". A transition amplitude $\langle \psi |S| \phi \rangle$ is a matrix element of the (unitary) scattering operator $S$.

Since $A$ is an observable, it must be Hermitian, so we can conclude that it has some real eigenvalues $a_k$ and orthonormal eigenvectors $|A_k\rangle$ labeled by $k$: $A=\sum_k a_k |A_k\rangle\langle A_k|$. When you measure the observable $A$, you get one of the results $a_k$ with probability $P(a_k|\psi)=|\langle A_k|\psi\rangle|^2$ (read as "probability of $a_k$ given that the state was $\psi$"). If you want to know what result you get on average, it is the sum of all $a_k$ weighted by the probability of measuring that value:
$$\mathrm{Average}(A|\psi)=\sum_k a_k P(a_k|\psi)=\sum_k a_k \langle \psi|A_k\rangle\langle A_k|\psi\rangle=\langle \psi|A|\psi\rangle.$$ This is what we call the expectation value - it is the expected value on average for this operator $A$ for this state $\psi$.
You can put the assumption wherever you want, but the axiom of quantum theory is typically that of the probability with which you get a particular measurement result (defining our $P$). This will be generalized slightly for density matrices but the same concept holds.

As for the transition amplitude, it depends in what context you discovered this. A direct answer is to consider a unitary operator $U$ instead of $A$ (although there are a few cases of unitary operators that are also Hermitian). Then one can consider an initial state $|\psi\rangle$ that evolves to $|\psi^\prime\rangle=U|\psi\rangle$ and do a measurement on the evolved state. In general, a measurement says "is my state more like this or more like that?" When we talked about $A$, we were asking how similar the state was to each eigenvector of $A$ and our measurement always found on or another value $a_k$. We can consider a measurement that says "is our evolved state $|\phi\rangle$?" To do that, we need a complete measurement, so we have one eigenvector of $A$ that is $|\phi\rangle$ with eigenvalue $1$ and we make all of the other eigenvectors of $A$ be orthogonal to $|\phi\rangle$ and all have eigenvalues 0, such that our measurement says "yes" (ie outcome 1) when we find our state to be like $|\phi\rangle$ and "no" (ie outcome 0) for all other states. Then the expectation value of such an operator $A=|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|+0$, when taken with respect to the evolved state $U|\psi\rangle$, is
$$\mathrm{Average}(A|U\psi)=|\langle\phi|U|\psi\rangle|^2=P(1|U\psi).$$
That is to say, the transition amplitude is the thing that gets squared to yield the probability of success for a measurement trying to find the evolved state $U|\psi\rangle$ to be in state $|\phi\rangle$.

If you want $A$ to just be Hermitian and not unitary, then $\langle \phi|A|\psi\rangle$ shows up in some calculations but is not as directly tied to a specific physical phenomenon (see perturbation theory, scattering matrices, weak values, etc.), so there is no direct reason why it should be interpreted in the same way as an expectation value. The weak value community will say it is like an expectation value if you normalize it by $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle$.

Thank you. And regarding my former question, how does one argue that the transition amplitude becomes expectation value when $\phi \rightarrow \psi$?

The matrix elements of $A$ are the transition amplitudes only in a first order time-dependent perturbation. They just happen to be the linear part of the expansion (Dyson series) but many terms follow.
